# Getting Pairs with Same Values SQL

Tags: sql

I have a table with two columns formatted as below:

```
Name    Gross
Smith   10,000
John    12,000
Doe     10,000
Joe     12,000
```

What is the query to return the pairs of people who have the same gross? In this case my output would be:

Smith, Doe

John, Joe

Comment: which DBMS are you using ?

Answer (score 3):

You are looking for a self-join

```
select t1.name, t2.name
from t t1 join
     t t2
     on t1.gross = t2.gross and t1.name < t2.name;
```

The `<` just ensures that each pair is present once.

Answer (score 1):

Your query should be like below :

```
select s1.Name,s2.Name
from salary s1 , salary s2
where s1.Gross = s2.Gross and s1.Name < s2.Name
```

Answer (score 0):

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/63c09/5)

**MS SQL Server 2017 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE MyTable (Name varchar(255), Gross int)
INSERT INTO MyTable (Name,Gross) VALUES ('Smith', 10), ('John', 12),
                     ('Doe', 10),('Joe', 12)
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT A.name AS P1, B.name AS P2
FROM MyTable A INNER JOIN
     MyTable B
     ON A.gross = B.gross and A.Name > B.Name
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/63c09/5/0)**:

```
|    P1 |  P2 |
|-------|-----|
| Smith | Doe |
|  John | Joe |
```